# Getting started with Highmaps tooltips

Tags: highcharts

I've created a basic fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/philu/3n9at5d0/) : - the map JS is:

```
$(function () {
     // Initiate the chart
     $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        title: {
           "text": "Simple Map"
        },
        series: [
            {
                "name": "07 March 2019",
                "type": "map",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "value": 23,
                        "name": "Blue",
                        "path": "M0,-994L204,-994L203,-480,0,-477z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Yellow<br>is the colour of...",
                        "path": "M204,-994L455,-994L457,-477,203,-480z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Red",
                        "path": "M455,-994,697,-991,700,-481,457,-477z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Green",
                        "path": "M697,-991,998,-992,1000,-480,700,-481z"
                    }
                ]   
            }
        ]
     });
  });
```

So, two questions:

1. If no "value" is set, it defaults to 0.  How can I just have nothing show instead?
2. The series name (which I have set to the date) shows on every label. If I leave this blank, I just get the blue dot to its left - again: how can I have nothing show instead? (ie no blue dot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the [plotOptions.series.tooltip](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.tooltip) object.

Sounds like you want these settings (inside series object):

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: "",
    pointFormat: "{point.name}"
},
```

[Forked fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/L8hebs2q/) and see the docs linked above for more options.